# mod rewrite htaccess file does not work properly by removing .php extention in lamp server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

php file in my webpage extenstion so i used .htaccess with mod_rewrite enable in wamp server .. It worked fine the url of the webpage will be

localhost/test/about  instead of localhost/test/about.php

With the same code i just tested my website in lamp server(ubuntu host) but it does not worked. i have enabled mod_rewrite in ubuntu server..

Let see my .htaccess code

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I dont know why it does not works.. is there any thing other than enabling mod_rewrite in my lamp server..

Thanks in advance

And also need to know good tutorial for creating .htaccess for multi purpose in webpage

like

blog/121 instead of blog?id=121

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for hiding .php extension:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Make sure above is placed in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file.

Comment: What is the location of above .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a blank page check the following values in the file

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```